# will_paginate mistaking a relation for an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Rails 5 application with will_paginate has the following log entry:

```
  Usercontent Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "usercontents".* FROM "usercontents" WHERE (id IN (171,172,33,34,35,156,173,144,78,81,88,90,93,96,36,37,38,48,87,89,94,39,175,176) AND  contenttype_id = 1)
   ↳ app/controllers/travels_controller.rb:45
```

and the controller action specifies

```
@points = Usercontent.where('id IN (?) AND  contenttype_id = ?', @all_valid_usercontents, 1).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 18)
```

if I run in the console that line as

```
@points = Usercontent.where('id IN (?) AND  contenttype_id = ?', [171,172,33,34,35,156,173,144,78,81,88,90,93,96,36,37,38,48,87,89,94,39,175,176], 1).paginate(page: 1, per_page: 18)
```

then

```
> @points.class
=> Usercontent::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

Inserting in the controller debugging points:

```
Rails.logger.info @a_points.class
Rails.logger.info @points.class
```

returns

```
Usercontent::ActiveRecord_Relation
Usercontent::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

View

```
<div id='yield_pcontent'>
  <%= render 'points' %>
</div>
<div id="infinite-scrolling">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

partial _points.html.erb

```
<div id=points class='tableize'>
  <%= render partial: 'point', collection: @points %>
</div>
```

How can will_paginate thus recognize helper <%= will_paginate %> as an array

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x00007f9a27d47718>
```

*note: adding `require 'will_paginate/array'` does not change this behaviour*

**update**

```
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:125:in `method_missing'
will_paginate (3.1.7) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:73:in `will_paginate'
will_paginate (3.1.7) lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb:33:in `will_paginate'
app/views/travels/_region_points.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_travels__region_points_html_erb__2375899185333558082_70150028432340'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:344:in `block in render_partial'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:333:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:312:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:49:in `render_partial'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:36:in `render'
app/views/travels/cc.html.erb:33:in `_app_views_travels_cc_html_erb___2132430413937746159_70149902220280'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/jerdvo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:31:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
wicked_pdf (1.2.2) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:46:in `call'
wicked_pdf (1.2.2) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:46:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
wicked_pdf (1.2.2) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:30:in `render'
app/controllers/travels_controller.rb:59:in `cc'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

**Update 2**
based on a suggestion, two behaviours are being observed:

```
<%= will_paginate %>  => undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x00007f9a261e2540>
<%= will_paginate @points %> => undefined method `total_pages' for #<Usercontent::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f9a26d07ab0>
```

Comment: Could you check what `@points` is just before calling `will_paginate`? eg. `<% byebug %>` (or whatever you like to debug with) the line above `<%= will_paginate %>`.

Comment: #<Usercontent::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005634fcb46130>  and question updated.  And if I remove the will_paginate reference, this percolates to the view.

Comment: Based upon your second update I'd look in the *TravelsController* and check if the `paginate` scope is set correctly upon the `@points` variable in the method `app/controllers/travels_controller.rb:59`. If you can't find anything could you add the method from whom line 59 is part to the question?

Comment: Yes, I'd picked up on that... `@points = Usercontent.where('id IN (?) AND  contenttype_id = ?', @all_valid_usercontents, 1).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 18)` while the logger tells me it is a relation. Last comment: I believe it is not pertinent.  it is the last line of the action before the render command: `      @fav = Fav.new   [...]      render layout: 'mps'`  Your thought of somethign quirky going on with will_paginate sounds ever-more realistic.  I am going to try and isolate the case with less components to see when, if not where, it trips up.

Answer (score 0):

He is waiting for an Object, not an Array. I share my solution, adapt it to your case.

```rb
def render_partial_resource(resources)
    if resources.present?
      if resources.respond_to?(:model_name)
        folder = resources.model_name.name.pluralize.downcase
        partial = resources.model_name.name.downcase
      else
        folder = resources.object.name.pluralize.downcase
        partial = resources.object.name.downcase
      end

      resources.map do |resource|
        render partial:"#{folder}/#{partial}", locals:{"#{partial}": resource}
      end.join(" ").html_safe
    end
  end
```